# How do I reshape this tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a `torch.tensor` that looks like this:

```
tensor([[[A,B,C],
         [D,E,F],
         [G,H,I]],

        [[J,K,L],
         [M,N,O],
         [P,Q,R]]]
```

I want to reshape this tensor so that its dimensions are `(18, 1)`. I want the new tensor to look like this:

```
tensor([A,
        J,
        B,
        K,
        C,
        L,
        D,
        M,
       ...
        I,
        R])
```

I've tried `tensor.view(-1,1)` but this doesn't work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
a = torch.arange(18).view(2,3,3)

print(a)
#tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2],
#         [ 3,  4,  5],
#         [ 6,  7,  8]],
#
#        [[ 9, 10, 11],
#         [12, 13, 14],
#         [15, 16, 17]]])

aa = a.permute(1,2,0).flatten()

print(aa)
#tensor([ 0,  9,  1, 10,  2, 11,  3, 12,  4, 13,  5, 14,  6, 15,  7, 16,  8, 17])
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `view` or `reshape` work in here:

```
t = torch.tensor([[[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]],

        [[1,2,3],
         [1,2,3],
         [1,2,3]]])
print(t.size())
t = t.permute(1,2,0).reshape(-1,1)
print(t)
print(t.size())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could be doing something wrong but when I run this code I get `[1,2,3,4,5,6,...,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3]` and this is not what I want!

Comment: Uncomment the code `t = t.reshape(-1,1)` instead of `t = t.reshape(-1)`

Comment: This gives the same result

Comment: `t = t.reshape(-1,1)` returns "torch.Size([18, 1])" on my end.

Comment: I see, the order matters now ;)